# is there a way to sort data depends on a value on excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013

I want to put some excel in row if they contain a specific word

```
 A              |B
 ____________________
 HP SERVER      | 1
 HP LAPTOP      | 2
 DELL SERVER    | 2
 LENOVO LAPTOP  | 3
 HP SERVER G8   | 2
```

I want the result to be sorting all SERVER in row like this

```
 A              |B
 ____________________
 HP SERVER      | 1
 DELL SERVER    | 2
 HP SERVER G8   | 2
 HP LAPTOP      | 2
 LENOVO LAPTOP  | 3
```

is there any way to do that with formula or VBA
I am using Microsoft Office 2013

Comment: Yes, check [SEARCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/search-searchb-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and combine it with an IF to get a number in B, and then sort it.

Comment: I don't want to sort depends on B I want to sort depend on A contains the word SERVER

Comment: To sort it as you want, you'll need an auxiliary column. I said B, but it could be anywhere. Based only in column A is not possible even with VBA, because you would need a complex macro that order all ranges copying and moving rows according to a value. Your best option is, indeed, the auxiliary/helper column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution is indeed with auxiliary column.

Put this formula in C column :

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("server";A1)));"A";"B")
```

Then sort on column C and all row with "server" keyword in column A will appear first.

Comment: it worked just fine 
Just replacing every ";" with ','
Thanx man that was really very helpfull

Comment: This is exactly what I said in the comments. An Auxiliary column with a formula with SEARCH and IF combined. Upvoted.